# SQL query for retrieving records with same name and recently created one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Table name Taxes.

```
id     | name            | value  | created_at           | updated_at 
:----: | :----:          | :----: | :-------:            | :----:
1      | VAT             | 9.56   | 2017-01-10 09:25:40  | 2017-01-10 09:25:40
:----- | :-----          | :----: | :-----               | :----
2      | Service Tax     | 10.56  | 2017-01-10 10:25:40  | 2017-01-10 10:25:40
:----- | :-----          | :----: | :-----               | :----
3      | Service charge  | 11.56  | 2017-01-10 11:25:40  | 2017-01-10 11:25:40
:----- | :-----          | :----: | :-----               | :----
4      | vat             | 2.56   | 2017-01-12 08:25:40  | 2017-01-12 08:25:40
:----- | :-----          | :----: | :-----               | :----
5      | service charge  | 21.56  | 2017-01-13 09:25:40  | 2017-01-13 09:25:40
:----- | :-----          | :----: | :-----               | :----
6      |  Service tax    | 21.56  | 2017-01-21 09:25:40  | 2017-01-21 09:25:40
:----- | :-----          | :----: | :-----               | :----
7      | Vat             | 12.56  | 2017-01-23 09:25:40  | 2017-01-23 09:25:40
:----- | :-----          | :----: | :-----               | :----
8      | Serivce Charge  | 16.56  | 2017-01-23 10:25:40  | 2017-01-23 10:25:40
:----- | :-----          | :----: | :-----               | :----
```

I have to retrieve latest created tax of each tax.

Output Expected:

```
    id    | name        | value  | created_at           | updated_at 
   :----: | :----:      | :----: | :-------:            | :----:
    6     |  Service tax| 21.56  | 2017-01-21 09:25:40  | 2017-01-21 09:25:40
   :----- | :-----          | :----: | :-----               | :----
    7     | Vat             | 12.56  | 2017-01-23 09:25:40  | 2017-01-23 09:25:40
   :----- | :-----          | :----: | :-----               | :----
    8     | Serivce Charge  | 16.56  | 2017-01-23 10:25:40  | 2017-01-23 10:25:40
```

Please help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result? Can you also show us your current query attempt? And tag the dbms you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL server and Oracle

```
with taxes as
(
select id, name, value, row_number() over(partition by name order by created_at desc) as tax_ord
from table1
)
select *
from taxes
where tax_ord = 1
```

MySQL

```
select a2.*
from 
(select name, max(created_at) as Max_Create
from table1
group by name) a1
inner join table1 a2
on a1.name = a2.name
and a1.Max_Create = a2.created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should work at least for MySQL:

```sql
select * from tax t
where (t.name, t.created_at) IN 
  (select t2.name, max(t2.created_at) from tax t2
   group by t2.name)
```

Comment: If the list of names is long the performance of IN drops rapidly, better to use a join.  Also, you need addition brackets...  `IN ( (<Subquery>) )`  The outer brackets to denote the list, the inner brackets to denote the subquery.

Comment: @MatBailie: I agree concerning performance (though I don't thing that this an issue here). Concerning brackets: are you sure? I tested the query and it worked.